# space images in PDF using R

Tags: r, image-processing, pdf-generation

I'm using R to generate PDFs that contain QR code images. The images have to be arranged in a 4x6 pattern like this mockup that i made in Word:

[image]

I've written a loader that i plan to write into a loop later on (i've got over 2000 images). However, i can't quite get the spacing right. This is my current result:

[image]

It's not a bad thing that the images are smaller, but the large margins on top and bottom and right are a problem. I've been trying to set par(mar = c(4,0,0,0) in the loop to see if the images would get a bottom margin, but that doesn't happen. Also, i think i need to use padding instead of margin, but i haven't found a parameter for padding.

Is there a way to do this? The code i've written so far:

```
# import libraries
library(qrcode)
library(imager)

# clear workspace
rm(list = ls())

filenames <- list.files(path = "./QR/2/")

im <- load.image(paste0("./QR/2/",filenames[1]))

im <- list()
for(i in 1:24){
  im[[i]] <- load.image(paste0("./QR/2/",filenames[i]))
}

pdf("./QR/2/stickervellen/1.pdf", paper = "a4")
par(mfrow = c(6,4), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
for(i in 1:24){
  par(mar = c(4,0,0,0))
  plot(im[[i]], axes = F)
}
dev.off()
```

the images i'm using can be found here: https://easyupload.io/v4gmbf

Comment: Please don't include `rm(list = ls())` in your code posted on SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the size of your graphics region with `width` and `height`. If you don't do that, default values (7 inch) are used and for an A4 paper which has a height of 11.7 inch you won't get full coverage.

```r
pdf("./QR/2/stickervellen/1.pdf", paper="a4", width=8.3, height=11.7)
par(mfrow=c(6, 4), mar=rep(0, 4))
for(i in 1:24){
  plot(im[[i]], axes=F)
  box()
}
dev.off()
```

[image: QR codes]

Please note that I added `box()` in your code so that the extent of the individual plots and the margins around them are visible.

In `?pdf` you may also find that if you specify the `paper` argument

> if either width or height is less than 0.1 or too large to give a total margin of 0.5 inch, it is reset to the corresponding paper dimension minus 0.5.

That's why there will always be a small margin around the whole page when you specify `paper`. If you don't want that margin, just leave out `paper="a4"` and you will get this:

[image: QR codes without margin]